Received Expired Id Token while Google Authentication in Flutter
I am trying to get Id token Using Google Authentication But when I check Received Token Using below API I am getting Error how to resolve It ?
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={your_token}
  Future<Map<String, String>?> googleSignIn({required String errorTitle}) async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      if (googleUser == null) {
        // User canceled the sign-in
        alertDialogue(title: errorTitle, description: "Discard the process");
        await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
        return null;
      }

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );


      final UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      final User? user = userCredential.user;


      if (user != null) {
        final String email = user.email!;
        final String? idToken = await user.getIdToken();

        if (idToken != null) {
        Map<String, String> authData = {'email': email, 'id_token': idToken, "source": "android"};
          return authData;
        } else {
          alertDialogue(title: errorTitle, description: "Unable to Login");
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error,trace) {
      print('Error during Google sign-in: $error');
      print('Error during Google sign-in: Trace : $trace');
      return null;
    }
  }

